# ClamAV unofficial sigs

Tags: clamav

Inside Synaptic Packages Manager, there is a ***clamav-unofficial-sigs*** app.

Is it absolutely necessary to install it?

If we have installed it, Is a good idea to uninstall it?

Comment: All it is used for is downloading and testing third party signatures:  https://linux.die.net/man/8/clamav-unofficial-sigs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use apt to discover** what packages do.

Here is an example:

```
$ apt show clamav-unofficial-sigs
...
 This package provides a script for updating the following sources of
 3rd-party clamav signatures until freshclamav gains support for such
 signatures.
 .
 The SaneSecurity/OITC signatures provide detection of phishing, spear
 phishing, fake lottery, ecard malware, casino, fake jobs, fake loans,
 419s, fake diplomas, porn, emailed malware and other general spam.
 .
 MSRBL signatures provide detection of image spam and general spam.
 .
 SecuriteInfo signatures provide various badware signatures,
 securiteinfo.com honeypot signatures, honeynet.cz signatures
 and French anti-spam signatures
 .
 MalwarePatrol provides detection of mail containing URLs to malware.
```